# How to correctly align buttons using CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know similar questions have been asked here before and I did read them, but I just can't seem to get it right regardless of what I try. Apologies, started looking at HTML/CSS about a week ago so I'm as new as can be.

So I have a flexbox as top navigation bar and am trying to evenly space out the buttons across the bar in a single row. However whatever I seem to try it keeps stacking each button on top of each other, resulting in 1 row per button --> 3 rows.

Code is below, thanks for any help or suggestions!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex: 2;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav buttons */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}

/*Dropdown content (hidden by default)*/
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: inherit;}
.topnav:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.topnav:hover .dropbtn {background-color: inherit;}
/* Change color on hover */
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Step 1: Header</h1>
    <p>Subheading</p>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Professional</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="first.php" >Professional</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hobbies</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="second.php" >Test</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tutorials</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="third.php" >Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: FYI, it is completely useless with all those `display: *` for prefixed/older variants to make it a flex container, when you later doesn't do the same on all the other flex properties like `justify-content: space-between;`. Do note, **all** Flexbox properties need the same prefix/old names/values for it to work cross browsers.

Comment: hey LGSon thanks for the info, however I don't really understand the implications of what you're saying... Could you elaborate?

Comment: E.g., to make it work in older IE10, which use an older version of Flexbox, you used `display: -ms-flexbox;`, which is fine, and then you used `flex-direction: row;`. IE10 doesn't know what `flex-direction: row;` is, it needs its prefixed version, `-ms-flex-direction: row;` or else it won't work. And the same goes for `flex-wrap`, which should be `-ms-flex-wrap`, and so on. Does this make sense ? ... Think of how one sometimes need `-moz` to make a _property_ work on older FF. This is the same, and **all** properties used need their prefixed version to work on a given browser.

Comment: [This article shows](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)  a few more browser versions for some of the properties.

Comment: @LGSon thank you! That makes a lot of sense, to be honest I simply grabbed that bit of CSS from another post here on SO without thinking too much about it's purpose. This is really helpful information especially to a newbie like myself so thanks again :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Basically I wrapped all `.topnav`'s with a `div` with class `parent`

the parent class has the following CSS

```
.parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex: 2;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Header/Blog Title */

.header {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex: 2;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  position: relative;
}


/* Style the topnav buttons */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}


/*Dropdown content (hidden by default)*/

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.topnav:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.topnav:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Step 1: Confucius</h1>
  <p>He who copies the master, honours him</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Professional</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="first.php">Professional</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hobbies</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="second.php">Test</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tutorials</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="third.php">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that accomplished what I was looking for! However I don't quite understand why I need to add the extra class and nest the navigation bar itself in it, maybe you could explain the reasoning because my assumption was that changing the navbar would be enough to edit the .dropbtn child element

Comment: @Nick, Flexbox requires a parent with display flex. In your code, that parent was the body. Because of this, I added a wrapper div with display flex

Comment: Ahh okay that does make sense.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I guess ,this is what your are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="second.css">
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

/* Style the top navigation bar */
.nav-wrap{
display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;

  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the topnav buttons */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}

/*Dropdown content (hidden by default)*/
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: inherit;}
.topnav:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.topnav:hover .dropbtn {background-color: inherit;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <h1>Step 1: Confucius</h1>
    <p>He who copies the master, honours him</p>
  </div>
 <div class="nav-wrap">
  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Professional</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="first.php" >Professional</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hobbies</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="second.php" >Test</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="dropbtn">Tutorials</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="third.php" >Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Included `<div class="nav-wrap">`